# How should i go about list of know building being display base on where you are c#

Tags: c#, google-maps

My company has list of known of for example shops in UK , we send our drivers out to check on our branches ; how would I go about displaying nearest shop to the driver base on his location

I have search but am not sure how would I add my company's list of known shops to say google map api  or would I need to read my list of known shops say it about 1000 and then base on driver location how would you select the nearest shop to him using google map api or something.

I hope the above make sense I have not started any coding yet as i am still trying to research into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a given location (lat,lng) you can search for the nearest shops with [Places API Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby).

Use `rankby=distance` to get the nearest results first, and use a `type` that matches that of the shops you're searching for. Then filter results by `name` or, if you have the ones for the targeted shops, `place_id`.